# Why am I losing the first item in my combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

After the `Form_Load` event, everything looks normal.  When I scroll down the list in the `bound combo box` , the selected item is then in the list twice and the first item in the combo box is never to be seen again.  When I scroll to the top of the list I get the correct `ID column` but the `display item` is the same as the last selected.

Here is my `Form Load` event

```
private void Purchase_Order_Info_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.purchase_Order_DataSet.Inventory);
    this.purchase_OrderTableAdapter.Fill(this.purchase_Order_DataSet.Purchase_Order);
    this.purchase_Order_ItemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.purchase_Order_DataSet.Purchase_Order_Items);
    part_NumberComboBox.Select();
}
```

I have many other forms with a `bound combobox` and have not run into this so I am completely confused.

Comment: some code sharing might help us. How are you adding item in the combobox ?

Comment: I am not adding to the `combobox`.  It's just being filled by the .Fill command in the `form_Load`.  I have deleted the `part_NumberComboBox` from the form and added a blank `combobox` from the `toolbox` and re-set the bindings and the problem is fixed.  It really doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: The code you supplied is not causing your problem.   You need to provide the code that is handling events (like index changing event?) or any other code that is mucking around with the combobox.  Also, you are not filling the combobox in the code you provided.  You are filling DataSets.

Comment: That's just it.  My form is created with drag and drop from `Data Source` and when I run it, the problem happens.  I did a test with a blank form and only dropped the first table adapter and had the problem.  I will do it again and post the code if you think you can find the problem.